# Want Ubuntu and Windows both on My Laptop

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, windows, uefi, secure-boot

Some days ago i used Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for 2 weeks and loves it. On that time i had completely install Ubuntu on my laptop. Now the problem is i also has to developed .Net applications. So i need both Windows and Ubuntu on my laptop.

1 - First I tried to install on Oracle Virtual Box, but found that my laptop doesn't support visualization. So it can't be install via Virtual Box.

2 - Then i tried to install Ubuntu alongside windows but see that there was no option given for such.

3 - Then i free up some space on my hard drive and try again, and see that no un-allocated space was shown during installation Ubuntu.

then i read this [article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported),

when i run **Confirm-SecureBootUEFI** command on powershell, it says **Cmdlet not supported on this platform**

Comment: Can you tell us if is it a Windows 7/8/Vista/10? Maybe it can help us solving this problem. =)

Comment: Window 8.1 64 bit

Comment: So you are able to start from the installation CD/USB-Stick? If so, the article you have linked has nothing to do with this problem. Also please attach images of where exactly during installation you are unsure. When being asked for where to install Ubuntu select "Something else" and attach a picture of that screen as well.

Comment: Check these Screen Shot of My Problem, https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2og9yj7rlqem2b5/AADXffpKn5CLetyD67rHcQIma?dl=0

Comment: You could just install both of them on separate partitions within the same hdd. If you don't mind!

Comment: i had installed ubuntu on this way but after the installation is finished, on start up it doesn't give the option for which windows to start ubuntu or windows 8.1?

Comment: i have un-allocated 100 gb partition on my hard. but still during installation id doesn't show the unallocated space after selection some thing else option.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing from the screenshots, your hard drive contains no operating system at the moment, which means you have to install both OSes from scratch. You should install Windows first, then Ubuntu, choosing to install it alongside the existing installation of Windows.

You can find information about installing Ubuntu alongside Windows on the [WindowsDualBoot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) help article from the Ubuntu website. You should install Ubuntu after Windows for the reasons mentioned in that article. The line "Cmdlet not supported on this platform" in your post means your laptop does not feature Secure Boot, so there should be no other steps required.

Once both systems are installed, GRUB2 (Ubuntu's default bootloader) will allow you to choose between Windows and Ubuntu at every startup.

Comment: The windows 8.1 is installed on my hard drive but Ubuntu installation says that no OS at the moment.. strange...